# Trying To Test "Webbrowser" And The Site Doesn't Show Up

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser

Okay so I'm trying to test a little module I found called Webbrowser, and I'm using an online IDE called repl.it and it seems to work fine, I don't know if this is the IDE or just me inputting it wrong but when I try to open any website a white screen comes up in place of it. Code >>>

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://discord.com')
webbrowser.open_new('http://discord.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the `webbrowser.open()` function instead.

```py
webbrowser.open("https://discord.com")
```

There may be a issue with REPL, as it cannot open new windows on your computer. I would recommend installing Python to your own computer and using a local IDE, which will allow you to run this properly.

Comment: I've tried to use that but no matter what I've tried to so far it doesn't wanna work

Comment: Then it is likely an issue with REPL. REPL likely doesn't support opening new tabs/windows on your browser.

Comment: oh okay! Thank you, I'll just try using atom or something instead then